# Show text under a dropdown menu selection

Tags: css, html

I would like to show a simple text string underneath a dropdown selection option. The plan is to have code available to be copied after someone selects a location from the drop down. As in if they select "Canada" in the drop down menu, under it will show a copy and pastable link that they can post on their website linking back to mine.

I am hoping I can do this in as simple way as possible as I am definitely no expert when it comes to coding so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to use JavaScript? Edit your question after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much! I changed some stuff to get it to show what I wanted but all in all exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one and add a href link on `contentText` so it will trigger on the dropdown you choose

```js
function ChangeText()
                        {
                          var contentText;
                          var selectedITem='';
                        var parm = document.getElementById("mySelection");
                          selectedITem =parm.options[parm.selectedIndex].text;
                          if(selectedITem == 'Canada')
                            contentText = '<a href="#">Canada</a>'
                         else  if(selectedITem == 'Philippines')
                            contentText = '<a href="#">Philippines</a>'
                         else  if(selectedITem == 'USA')
                            contentText = '<a href="#">USA</a>'   
                          
                          
    str=contentText;
     $("#test").html(str);
                          

                        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                                                
             <select id="mySelection" onchange="ChangeText();" style="width: 100%;">
               
             <option disabled="disabled"   selected="selected">Select method</option>
                  <option value="1">Canada</option>
                  <option value="2">Philippines</option>
                  <option value="3">USA</option>
                   </select>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          
          <div  id="test"> 
             
          </div>
```